# Why isn't my favicon appearing in Safari?

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, favicon

I have added a favicon to my website build (currently on my local machine) using the below code and it appears as it should in Chrome. When I open the file in Safari and bookmark the page the icon doesn't show up (just a letter) and the same on my MacBook touchbar...
I used this website to generate my favicon https://realfavicongenerator.net

Will it not show because it is sitting on my local machine?
I know it is a small thing in a website build but I would like to get it right! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicon_package_v0.16/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon_package_v0.16/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon_package_v0.16/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon_package_v0.16/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="favicon_package_v0.16/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="favicon_package_v0.16/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#079992">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#bdc3c7">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Comment: RealFaviconGenerator's author speaking :) When you say your site is on your local machine, do you mean that you simply access your site as files? Or do you have a local web server? In the first case (file), what you observe is normal. Come back to this issue only once you can access your site via HTTP.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I am just loading the html file into my web browser at the moment as the website isn’t complete. I thought that may well be the case - thanks for clarifying! I will come back to you if I run into problems once the site is live. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Delete Safari’s favicon cache
If you’re experiencing favicons that aren’t right, maybe they have icons for different websites, clearing the cache and starting over is a good option.

1. Close and quit Safari.
2. Using Finder, click Go > Go to Folder from the menu bar
3. Enter ~/Library/Safari/Favicon Cache/ in the pop-up window and click Go.
4. Select all items in the cache folder and move them to the Trash. You can select all with the keyboard shortcut Command + A and then drag them to your Trash or right-click and pick Move to Trash.

Source: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2020/09/08/refresh-favicons-in-safari-mac/